# How to set WorkBookSetting in Apache POI for whole WorkBook

Tags: java, apache-poi, jexcelapi

Currently I am Using JExcel to read existing xls. To set character encoding of workbook, I am using following code.

```
WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
String language=//
if(!"en".equals(language)){
   ws.setEncoding("Cp1252");
}
WorkBook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(myxls,ws);
```

While migrating to POI, I am not finding any alternative for `WorkbookSettings`. POI provides a method `setCharSet` in `HSSFFont` but I think it is for cell not a workbooksetting.
Do I need to handle this explicitly or I can ignore this in POI.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: What is that line supposed to be doing?

Comment: It sets character encoding of workbook to support different language characters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent of `WorkbookSettings.setEncoding` in Apache POI, because Apache POI handles all the encoding / unicode aspects of working with Excel files for you.

As long as you have correctly got your characters into Java in a String, then when you pass that String to Apache POI then it will be correctly written into the Excel file.